# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at Object.success

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, undefined

I am trying to inherit data from a `json` file to a select box, however I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>       at Object.success (http://localhost:4664/sublimeTest/app:6:35)
>       at i (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js:2:27603)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js:2:28369)
>       at A  cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js:4:13858)
>       at XMLHttpRequest. cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js:4:16146)

and here is my `html` code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>moco</title>
</head>
<body>
<select id="brand"></select>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

also here is the `app.js` code:

```
var $select = $('#марка');

$.getJSON('brand_json.json', function(data){
    $select.html('');

    for (var i = 0; i < data['brand'].length; i++){

        $select.append('option id="' + data['brand'][i]['id'] + data['brand'][i]['марка'] + '</option>');
        //                                  ime na select id vo html-ot
        //                                                                      ime na id vo json
    }
});
```

So I edited the code a bit but the select box is still not displaying the items though I am pretty sure it's inheriting them successfully. It's just not displaying them in the select box...

```
var select = $('#brand');

$.getJSON('brand_json', function(data){
    select.html('');

    // for (var i = 0; i < data.brand.length; i++){
    // $select.append("<option id=" + data['brand'][i]['id'] + ">" + data["brand"][i]["марка"] + "</option>");  

        var option = new Option(data.brand[0],data.brand[0]);
        $(select).append($(option));
        console.log(data.brand[0]);
        //var option = new Option(data.brand[i]["Марка"],data.brand[i]["Марка"]);
        //$(select).append($(option));
        });
```

Comment: `data['brand']` is most likely undefined, try loggin it

Comment: try `console.log(data);`

Comment: On a sitdenote, why are you including jquery library twice? Just use the minified version (`jquery.min.js`)